# How can I make a command execute exactly once in an AMS environment?

Tags: macros, conditionals, amsthm

I'm wanting to create a command similar to AMS's proof environment that automatically calls a command (like AMS's `\qedhere`) when it gets to the end, but allows you to call the command earlier if you need to.  In my case, I'm wanting the command to execute some code and place a label with a saved parameter.  When the command ends with text, the label is in the right spot.  But when the command ends with a displayed equation, the label is too far down.  In those cases, I'd like to manually move the label to its correct location.  In my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320454/107497), I found out how to do this in most cases.  But it turns out that my approach doesn't work with the AMS displayed equation environments (gather, align, and flalign), even though it works with the LaTeX equation environment.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\currentLabel}{\nosuchcommand}

\newcounter{exampleends}
\newif\ifendencountered

\newcommand{\exampleendhere}{\ifendencountered%
 \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
\else%
 \stepcounter{exampleends}%
 \label{e\currentLabel}%
 \textbf{End of \currentLabel.}%
 \global\endencounteredtrue%
% \renewcommand{\currentLabel}{\nosuchcommand}%
\fi%
}

\newcommand{\myexample}[2]{%
 \renewcommand{\currentLabel}{#1}%
 \endencounteredfalse%
 \textbf{Start of \currentLabel.}\label{#1}\\
 #2\exampleendhere}

\begin{document}

\myexample{labelDefault}{This is the default.
\begin{equation*}1+1=2\end{equation*}}

\bigskip\bigskip

\myexample{labelUsesEEH}{This uses exampleendhere.
\begin{equation*}1+1=2\exampleendhere\end{equation*}}

\bigskip\bigskip

\myexample{labelGather}{This should have ``End of labelGather'', but doesn't.
\begin{gather*}1+1=2\exampleendhere\end{gather*}}

\bigskip\bigskip

example end called: \arabic{exampleends} time(s) (should be 3)

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: example output]

I've looked at the source for amsthm.sty, but I can't understand how it does what it does, and how I could modify that to suit my needs.  Why does `gather` behave differently than `equation` in this case?  How can I make the "End of labelGather" appear?

Comment: While I don't know an immediate answer, I seem to recall that `amsmath` environments conduct several passes through their contents.  For example stepping a counter in such an environment results in a multi-count, unless special provisions are taken.

Comment: I think therefore, what is happening is that the label gets added on the first pass, but when `\endencountertrue` is then set, the label gets revoked for the second and subsequent passes.  You, of course, know that if you comment out the `\global\endencounteredtrue` line, the label appears...unfortunately, twice (which was the subject of your prior question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do `\global\endencounteredtrue` only in the “typesetting phase”, not in the measuring one. For this you can use `\ifmeasuring@`. You also need `\ltx@label` if you want it to work in `align`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\currentLabel}{\nosuchcommand}

\newcounter{exampleends}
\newif\ifendencountered

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\exampleendhere}{%
  \ifendencountered
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \else
    \stepcounter{exampleends}%
    \ltx@label{e\currentLabel}%
    \textbf{End of \currentLabel.}%
    \ifmeasuring@\else\global\endencounteredtrue\fi
% \renewcommand{\currentLabel}{\nosuchcommand}%
\fi
}

\newcommand{\myexample}[2]{%
   \renewcommand{\currentLabel}{#1}%
   \global\endencounteredfalse
   \textbf{Start of \currentLabel.}\label{#1}\\
   #2\exampleendhere
}

\begin{document}

\myexample{labelDefault}{This is the default.
\begin{equation*}1+1=2\end{equation*}}

\myexample{labelUsesEEH}{This uses exampleendhere.
\begin{equation*}1+1=2\exampleendhere\end{equation*}}

\myexample{labelGather}{This should have ``End of labelGather''
\begin{gather*}1+1=2\exampleendhere\end{gather*}}

\myexample{labelAlign1}{This should have ``End of labelAlign1''
\begin{align*}1+1=2\exampleendhere\end{align*}}

\myexample{labelAlign2}{This should have ``End of labelAlign2''
\begin{align*}1+1=2\exampleendhere\end{align*}}

example end called: \arabic{exampleends} time(s) (should be 3)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\ifmeasuring@` Who wouda thunk?  Magnificent! and potentially useful in a variety of applications.

Comment: @Teepeemm I fixed the code for usage with `align`