# Cannot use state of boolean variable in gather environment

Tags: amsmath

### Original Question

I intend to use the state of a boolean variable, then negate it. The negation must carry over to the next place where the variable is evaluated.

This works fine, except in some amsmath environments such as gather where the boolean variable always has the final value regardless of where it is evaluated within the environment.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifY\Yfalse
\newif\ifZ\Zfalse

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \ifY true \else false \fi
    \global\Ytrue
    \ifY true \else false \fi
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \ifY true \else false \fi
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
    \ifZ true \else false \fi
    \global\Ztrue
    \ifZ true \else false \fi
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
    \ifZ true \else false \fi
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Actual result:

- for `Y` in the equation environment: "false true true"
- for `Z` in the gather environemnt: "true true true"

Desired result:
"false true true" regardless of the environment.

How can this be done?

### Updated refined question

While I wanted to give @jasper-habicht credit for providing a working correct answer to my initial problem, the proposed solution is also not quite practical in my actual use case.

I therefore compiled a second MWE which is closer to what I want to accomplish in my actual application.

It includes a solution adopted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320586/107497 that @teepeemm pointed me at in a comment below. By using the `\ifmeasuring@` variable, the state of the boolean variable can be switched only in the final evaluation of the equation code, therefore producing the desired output also in multi-line amsmath environments (such as `gather`).

**Updated MWE *with solution***

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifY\Ytrue
\newif\ifZ\Ztrue

% Original code
\newcommand{\SpecialCommandY}{\ifY Y_\text{first} \global\Yfalse \else Y_\text{subsequent} \fi}
\newcommand{\SpecialCommandZ}{\ifZ Y_\text{first} \global\Zfalse \else Y_\text{subsequent} \fi}

% Improved code (produces desired result)
%\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\SpecialCommandY}{\ifY Y_\text{first} \ifmeasuring@\else\global\Yfalse\fi \else Y_\text{subsequent} \fi}
%\newcommand{\SpecialCommandZ}{\ifZ Y_\text{first} \ifmeasuring@\else\global\Zfalse\fi \else Y_\text{subsequent} \fi}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}

Desired:
\begin{equation}
    \SpecialCommandY
    \SpecialCommandY
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \SpecialCommandY
\end{equation}

Result of multi-line math environment:
\begin{gather}
    \SpecialCommandZ
    \SpecialCommandZ
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
    \SpecialCommandZ
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, the `gather` environment collects its contents to execute some measurements before it actually typesets it. Hence, `\global\Ztrue` will have been already executed the moment the typesetting of the first true/false happens. But it should work without `\global`.

Comment: mh, I see. In the actual application I do need the variable to be changed globally though. I'll refine the MWE.

Comment: This reminds me of a question I had along similar lines.  You can use `\ifmeasuring@` to make sure the `\global` only happens once: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320586/107497.

Comment: Thanks @Teepeemm the `ifmeasuring@` was the key!

Comment: @Teepeemm if you want to, you can add an answer where you copy-paste my updated MWE and I will mark it the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully sure, to be honest, but I think the `gather` environment collects its contents to do some measurement or the like, and only then typesets it. Obviously, during this process, `\globalZtrue` becomes already executed before the actual typesetting starts.

It seems that you can add to a hook at the very end of the environment setting the boolean globally which would then still be in the relevant scope but only executed once:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifZ\Zfalse

\AddToHook{env/gather/end}{\ifZ\global\Ztrue\else\global\Zfalse\fi}

\begin{document}

\ifZ true \else false \fi

\begin{gather}
    \ifZ true \else false \fi
    \Ztrue
    \ifZ true \else false \fi
\end{gather}

\ifZ true \else false \fi

\begin{gather}
    \ifZ true \else false \fi
    \Zfalse
    \ifZ true \else false \fi
\end{gather}

\ifZ true \else false \fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is true that `gather` measures, so that equation numbers can be placed properly.  This is one of the reasons that `gather` (like all `amsmath` multiline environments) should not be used for single-line equations.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The above is just to show that the setting of true and false would work. I don't know how the OP is going to use this anyways. But thank you for confirming what floated through my somewhat blurry memories =)

Comment: Marking as solution, because it solves the problem of my initial MWE. The solution is a little cumbersome (`\AddToHook` needed for every boolean variable, and type of amsmath multi-line environment, I guess) ... therefore not suitable for my application.

Comment: @Bastian Well, you would only need one `\AddToHook` for the `gather` environment. You can put all the needed variables in there. No need to call `\AddToHook` more than once. But sure, the `\ifmeasuring@` way is probably a nicer solution anyways.